# How to setup selenium , projects and eclipse at one central point like server so multiple tester can write automation code at same time?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to set **Eclipse**, **Selenium** and our projects at some central level from where other tester can access code, modify code, update code etc.

Until now I was alone doing automation scripting to my local pc using **Selenium** and **Java** in **Eclipse**. Now we have multiple testers that do automation scripting. So I want something like a server. How can I set up this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all the tests into a code [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system. Preferable in the same version control system as the application under test works with. This way the tests are version-ed with the code it tests. This way you could go back in time and build the application and run the tests against it. You will need this if you need to support multiple versions of the application.

The GIT version control system has a [free course at code school](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git) to get you started.

If your team is distributed have a look at online/hosted version control systems like:

- [Github](https://github.com/): only free if your code is public
- [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/): free for small team, not public
- [Visual Studio online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/version-control-vs): free upto 5 users

For local version control systems look at:

- Local git server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507489/git-server-like-github
- Stash: https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash
- TFS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server

Also why do I need version control? Read [this blog post](http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/mac/basics/why-use-version-control). (I even use version control when working alone, always!)

Comment: Thank you so much , But here I am using eclipse and Java so can I use TFS? Because I thought only asp.net developers use TFS to manage distributed code.

Comment: TFVC part of TFS can store any code also Java code. Version control systems are language/IDE in-depended. For eclipse + tfs read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913026.aspx If your teams uses C#/.Net why not also write the tests in that language? That way the Dev team can help you guys better! :)